# Configuring Group site with harmon.ie

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, harmon.ie

We are using Harmom.ie for Outlook to save e-mails and documents in SharePoint sites. Recently we started to use the Planner and Groups and we want to use Harmon.ie to save documents and emails into group sites. In Harmon.ie there is an option to enable groups sites. We have done that. When doing this an Office 365 Global admin must give consent. We also done that. However when a user try to access they are not allowed to access. According to the documentation something need to be set up on Azure giving the add proper Graph access.

The question is. How do we do this??? has anyone else got this to work? When we access the app on Azure there is not much we can do?

We are stock! any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to solve this. Harmon.ie also allows you to connect to teams & groups - and I suppose this is what you tried to do. We also did this. It was a little bit complex - but after some communication with the harmon.ie support, we got it working.

However, I am proposing a different way to solve your problem. Why? Currently, the problem with this teams and groups connection is, that you are not getting all the functionality of normal site connection (if you connect a SharePoint site to: https://www.harmon.ie). You are only going to see the documents library of your office group - and nothing else. But as an office group just uses a normal SharePoint Site, you could also have other libraries created.

What you can do is, get
1. get the site url (every office group has a SharePoint-Site behind)
2. and book it into harmon.ie manually

You will than have access to the document libraries.

for this solution, you do not need any additional configuration of teams and groups access.